# accessibility-insights@3 task fails in runtime dependency install

Tags: azure-pipelines, accessibility-insights

The yaml pipeline has the following tasks added and fails with dependency install.

- task: YarnInstaller@3
  inputs:
  versionSpec: '1.x'
- task: accessibility-insights@3
  inputs:
  hostingMode: 'staticSite'
  staticSiteDir: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\out\release\ProjectPkg\Code\wwwroot'
  singleWorker: true
  uploadOutputArtifact: true
  failOnAccessibilityError: true

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Accessibility Insights for Azure DevOps Extension v3 requires Node 16 to run. As part of our extension, we set a `minimumAgentVersion` variable that forces ADO to use an agent running Node 16 by default.

I see in the log that the pipeline is using `NODE_MODULE_VERSION 72` (Node 6) when it expects `NODE_MODULE_VERSION 93` (Node 16). Is there a task before this one that is setting the Node version? If so, you may be able to remove the task that installs Node 6 and use the Node 16 environment that will come as the default on the agent version forced by the Accessibility Insights task.

If this doesn’t work, you can try adding a task, like [Node.js Tool Installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/tool/node-js?view=azure-devops), to re-install Node 16 before the Accessibility Insights task runs:

```yaml
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '16.x'
```

Comment: Added the following before the accessibility task now gives me the following error.

      - task: NodeTool@0
        inputs:
          versionSpec: '6.x' 

Starting: accessibility-insights@3 (windows_build_container)
==============================================================================
Task         : Accessibility Insights Azure DevOps Task
Description  : Scan accessibility issues in an Azure DevOps pipeline
Version      : 3.0.0
Author       : Accessibility Insights
Help         : 
========================================================

Comment: Installing runtime dependencies
yarn install v1.22.19
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
error C:\__w\_tasks\accessibility-insights_4811a442-2fd3-5aa8-ba1a-14cb7e24c113\3.0.0\node_modules\puppeteer: Command failed.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
Exit code: 1
Command: node install.js
Arguments: 
Directory: C:\__w\_tasks\accessibility-insights_4811a442-2fd3-5aa8-ba1a-14cb7e24c113\3.0.0\node_modules\puppeteer
Output:

Comment: C:\__w\_tasks\accessibility-insights_4811a442-2fd3-5aa8-ba1a-14cb7e24c113\3.0.0\node_modules\puppeteer\install.js:29
async function download() {
      ^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token function
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:549:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:611:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)

Comment: at startup (bootstrap_node.js:160:9)
node:child_process:902
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Command failed: yarn install --prod --ignore-engines --frozen-lockfile
    at checkExecSyncError (node:child_process:828:11)
    at execSync (node:child_process:899:15)
    at installRuntimeDependencies (C:\__w\_tasks\accessibility-insights_4811a442-2fd3-5aa8-ba1a-14cb7e24c113\3.0.0\index.js:177245:34)
    at Object../src/index.ts (C:\__w\_tasks\accessibility-insights_4811a442-2fd3-5aa8-ba1a-14cb7e24c113\3.0.0\index.js:177216:63)

Comment: at __webpack_require__ (C:\__w\_tasks\accessibility-insights_4811a442-2fd3-5aa8-ba1a-14cb7e24c113\3.0.0\index.js:195046:42)
    at C:\__w\_tasks\accessibility-insights_4811a442-2fd3-5aa8-ba1a-14cb7e24c113\3.0.0\index.js:195113:37
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\__w\_tasks\accessibility-insights_4811a442-2fd3-5aa8-ba1a-14cb7e24c113\3.0.0\index.js:195116:12)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10) {
  status: 1,
  signal: null,
  output: [ null, null, null ],
  pid: 13400,

Comment: stdout: null,
  stderr: null
}
##[error]Exit code 1 returned from process: file name 'C:\Program Files\Docker\docker.EXE', arguments 'exec -i   5ab275e2af704919650595455100aa8081a5a6fb5a450398662d98ed5edf11e9 C:\__a\externals\node\bin\node.exe C:\__w\_temp\containerHandlerInvoker.js'.
Finishing: accessibility-insights@3 (windows_build_container)

Comment: I noticed you the `versionSpec` is set to `6.x`. The pipeline requires 16. You could try: `versionSpec: '16.15.0'` to set the Node version to 16.